# Workbench Delete or Unpublish Multiple Nodes

Tags: nodes, workbench

I have recently installed work bench, when we view all contents there is no option to select multiple nodes and apply delete or unpublish action on them. I need to edit each node and then delete each node separately. Please suggest any solution.

Comment: If it's a view, then views_bulk_operations module will allow you to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I cloned the ie. needs-review view

and added field "views bulk operations: Content", marked a few possible actions,

rearranged the fields so bulk ops are first col as one expects

and that's it.